# Create RadioButton Dynamically with String Array

Tags: android

i m trying to create RadioButton from String Array but it is not working if i use only String then it seems to work fine 
Log Cat Showing error  **"ava.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."**

i know that error is coming beacuse RadioButton Object is not Creating Dynamically, so that error is showing

i took the Code From here for Reference,Please check this url 
http://android.okhelp.cz/create-radiobutton-radiogroup-dynamically-android-sample/

Please check code and correct me so i will go further with my App 
Here is code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        // adding Radio Group
        layout.addView(radioGroup, p);

        // creating Radio buttons Object//
        RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
        String[] ab ={"1","2"}; 

        for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
        {
            radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
            radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
            ((ViewGroup)layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);
        }
```

and Log Cat Error

```
 I/Choreographer(4431): Skipped 547 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 D/AndroidRuntime(4431): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm(4431): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d2fb20)
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.radiobuttondynamic, PID: 4431
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.addView(RadioGroup.java:141)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
    at com.example.radiobuttondynamic.Radio_Button.onCreateOptionsMenu(Radio_Button.java:46)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 D/dalvikvm(4431): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 142K, 7% free 3094K/3308K, paused 107ms, total 113ms
```

Looking for help 
thanks

Comment: How does your XML looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You
>   must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Because you are adding same `RadioButton` instance  again in `LinearLayout`.

Create  object of `RadioButton` in for loop:

```
   for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
        ((ViewGroup)layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);
    }
```

inside for loop to avoid error.

Comment: You did it , i was looking for this from past three days.

Comment: my last Question,  i need to **give the Marign from TOP** , how i can give it ?

Comment: @AshuKumar: you can set margin for all RadioButton's by setting `p.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);`

Comment: one more question, can u please tell me how to get the value form created RadioButtons , but " radioButtonView" is not Recognize can u please tell me what i m doing wrong

Comment: @AshuKumar: please make other question for problem and my suggestion is you can get text from RadioButton using `radioGroup.getChildAt(index)`

Comment: sure , i will make another Question ,thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

If you have this array:-

```
String route[] = {"1", "3", "4"};
```

You can create radio buttons using the loop:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < route.length; i++) 
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButton.setText("Route " + String.valueOf(route[i]));
    radioButton.setId(i);
    rprms = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms);
}
```

And you can get the selected field using:-
(I am having SAVE button, so this code is written in onClick listener)
Else you can use onCheckedChangeListener also.

```
int selection = rgp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
for (int i = 0; i < route.length; i++) 
{
    if (i == selection)
        showToast("" + route[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is that you are trying to add the same RadioButton several times in the same layout, you have to move the Radiobutton creation inside the for cycle

```
    String[] ab ={"1","2"}; 

    for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
        ((ViewGroup)layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);
    }
```