# Populate a RadioGroup with RadioButtons from a string-array

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a layout that includes an empty `RadioGroup`. (I think this is the difference between this question and others that have been asked - I already have the empty RadioGroup in the correct place in my layout)

I'd like to populate this `RadioGroup` with the `item`s from a `string-array` that I have defined in `strings.xml`.

The array in `strings.xml` looks like this:

```
<string-array name="currency_symbols">
    <item>$ - Dollar</item>
    <item>€ - Euro</item>
    <item>£ - Pound</item>
    <item>¥ - Yen</item>
    <item># - Other</item>
</string-array>
```

I am then trying to create a `RadioButton` and add it to the RagioGroup with teh following:

```
RadioGroup currencySettingRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) settings_dialog.findViewById(R.id.rg_currency_symbol);
currencySettingRadioGroup.removeAllViews();

RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
String[] currency_symbols_options_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_symbols);
for ( String this_currency_option: currency_symbols_options_array ) {
    rb.setText(this_currency_option);
    currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb);
}
```

The `currencySettingRadioGroup.removeAllViews();` was added because I'm getting the following error, but it makes no difference:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

The line that is apparently causing the problem is the `currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb);` line...

How do I do this properly?

(I've looked at [Create RadioButton Dynamically with String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836405/create-radiobutton-dynamically-with-string-array) and the referenced http://android.okhelp.cz/create-radiobutton-radiogroup-dynamically-android-sample/ but can't seem to get anything to work)

Comment: You need to put this line `RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);` inside your `for` loop

Comment: Well, that's fixed it, but I cannot figure out why... by putting this inside the loop is a new instance of the `rb` object being created on each loop, but with the same name?

Comment: By having that line outside the loop you were creating only on instance of a RadioButton. And that one instance (a unique object) was being add to the RadioGroup several times creating an error.

Comment: Fat Monk :: you wrote "but with the same name?" . Do you mean that the Text is the same? Eg. "$ - Dollar" five times??

Comment: No, I mean that each time around the loop we create a new Radio button object called `rb`.

Comment: Really odd problem now. Moving the `new Radio Uttam(this)` line into the loop creates the `RadioGroup` properly BUT I am also using `setChecked(true)` on one of the options as it is created based on a setting from a Prefs file. Whichever button is set to be checked this way then behaves as though it is part of a seperate `RadioGroup`. All other buttons toggle but this one stays checked  as well. If I exit the screen and return with a different one selected via the Prefs file then it's is the new one that behaves oddly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your activity does or rather - what your ultimate goal is, but you might want to consider using a `Spinner` element.

Comment: I've got a number of spinners in the app, but a group of radio buttons fits this purpose far better - I've posted a separate question about the odd behaviour here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122143/strange-behaviour-of-programatically-created-radiogroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Barns52's comment, creating a new `RadioButton` each time around the `for`-loop (rather than just once before the `for`-loop starts) solves this issue.

The working code is as follows:

```
RadioGroup currencySettingRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) settings_dialog.findViewById(R.id.rg_currency_symbol);

String[] currency_symbols_options_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_symbols);
for ( String this_currency_option: currency_symbols_options_array ) {
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setText(this_currency_option);
    currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb);
}
```