# Strange behaviour of programatically created RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

I am programatically adding `RadioButtons` to a pre-existing but empty `RadioGroup` with the following code.

```
        RadioGroup currencySettingRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) currency_settings_dialog.findViewById(R.id.rg_currency_symbol);
        currencySettingRadioGroup.removeAllViews();

        RadioButton rb_none = new RadioButton(this);

        // Add the 'None' option at the start
        rb_none.setText("None");
        if (v_currency_symbol.equals("")) rb_none.setChecked(true);
        currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb_none,0);


        String[] currency_symbols_options_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_symbols);
        for ( int i=0; i < currency_symbols_options_array.length; i++ ) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
            rb.setText(currency_symbols_options_array[i]);
            if (v_currency_symbol.equals(currency_symbols_options_array[i].substring(0,1))) rb.setChecked(true);
            currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb,i+1);
        }
```

The layout XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/currency_settings_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/currency_symbol"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/currency_symbol_explanation" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_currency_symbol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_close_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/close_currency_settings"
        android:textColor="#008dcd" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `RadioGroup` gets built correctly and the `RadioButton` with the text that matches my `v_currency_symbol` variable's first character is checked as expected.

[image: Correct RadioButton selected when dialog opens]

However, clicking any of the other `RadioButton`s does not cause the checked option to uncheck - I end up with two options checked.

[image: Clicking another option does not uncheck first]

Clicking and checking any of the other options causes the second checked position to uncheck, but the first `RadioButton`remains checked.

[image: Other radio buttons behave like a separate radio group]

It is almost as though the `RadioButton` that is checked programatically belongs to a seperate RadioGroup.

Removing the two lines that check one of the `RadioButton`s on creation allows the `RadioGroup` to function properly, but you obviously cannot then see the previous selection.

Comment: Have you debugged on your code to know where the issue come from?, BTW the `None` radio button should be one of the radioGroup why you separated it?**`You added two radio button to the same radioGroup which mean that you will have two checked buttons`**

Comment: Everything seems to be working correctly other than the stuck button. `onClick` events on the `RadioButtons` are fired correctly etc to set the `v_currency_symbol` value correctly and when the dialog is closed and reopened the correct me value is shown as checked but then this one is stuck on. And the `None` option IS within the `RadioGroup` it is just not created from the array that is read by the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue... checking the `RadioButton` *before* adding it to the `RadioGroup` causes the problem.

Swapping the two relevant lines resolves the issue. The working code is as follows:

```
    // Add the 'None' option at the start
    rb_none.setText("None");
    currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb_none,0);
    if (v_currency_symbol.equals("")) rb_none.setChecked(true);


    String[] currency_symbols_options_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_symbols);
    for ( int i=0; i < currency_symbols_options_array.length; i++ ) {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText(currency_symbols_options_array[i]);
        currencySettingRadioGroup.addView(rb,i+1);
        if (v_currency_symbol.equals(currency_symbols_options_array[i].substring(0,1))) rb.setChecked(true);
    }
```